# Why is it valid to define a type as pointer to an undefined struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I was digging into a 3rd party code base and found that it is apparently valid to declare a type as a pointer to an undefined struct. As a minimum working example, consider a C file `test.c` containing nothing but:

`typedef struct foo *bar;`

What surprises me is that this file compiles without any problems using the command

`gcc test.c -shared`

Why does the compiler not complain about the struct foo not being declared anywhere?

My environment is Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609.

Comment: It is not "undefined struct", it is a pointer to incomplete type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration above creates a **forward declaration** of `struct foo`.  Although you can't access its members, you can operate on a pointer to it.

This is commonly referred to as an **opaque type**, and is used to hide implementation details of a library from users of the library.

For example a library implementation may contain the following:

lib.c:

```
struct foo {
  int f1;
};

struct foo *init()
{
    return malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
}

void set1(struct foo *p, int val)
{
    p->f1 = val;
}

int get1(struct foo *p)
{
    return p->f1;
}

void cleanup(struct foo *p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

The header file for this library might look like this:

lib.h:

```
struct foo;

struct foo *init(void);
void set1(struct foo *p, int val);
int get1(struct foo *p);
void cleanup(struct foo *p);
```

The user of this library would use the `init` function to create an instance of the struct and the `set1` and `get1` functions to read / update the member.  The user can't however create an instance of `struct foo` or access the members without going through one of the interface functions.

Comment: But yes that's possible because the pointer to it is same...that's why the forward declaration and all that

Comment: I think I'd actually turn that around, @coderredoc.  The fact that all pointers to structure types have the same size *follows* from the fact that C permits declaring incomplete structure types (i.e. with a tag but no body) and deriving pointers to such types.  The effect is that the size of structure pointers cannot be a function of the structure members.

Comment: Ah not it seems circular.. @JohnBollinger: Many a times I have read here the reverse.  I guess there is no valid way to know for sure..which drove what

Comment: Perhaps not, @coderredoc, but if I were to try, I would point out that the standard does not, in fact, guarantee that structure pointers are all the same size.  That just turns out to be a universal implementation decision.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.2.5 Types ¶28: _A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements._

Answer (score 1):

Because pointer to structs have same size (for any structs). The size of a structure pointer doesn't depend on it's definition. Because no matter what, the pointer to it would be behaved the same way as any other structures pointer.

Comment: I am surely missing something... if I write "pointer++", when pointer points to a forward declaration, how much the pointer gets incremented?

Comment: Just tried several ways; compiler complains with "error: increment of pointer to unknown structure" and "error: arithmetic on pointer to an incomplete type".

Comment: Made a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250911/pointer-to-unknown-or-incomplete-struct